# NoSuchMethodError:javax.xml.bind.annotation.XMLAccessorType.value()Ljavax.xml.bind.annotation.AccessType

Tags: java, jaxb

I am upgrading a java project from Java 1.5 to Java 1.8.  After changing the JRE in eclipse build path
i am getting below exception while running the application.

```
Execption in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:javax.xml.bind.annotation.XMLAccessorType.value()Ljavax.xml.bind.annotation.AccessType;
```

I am using below jar files in my project.

```
apache-logging-log4j.jar axis-1.4.jar axis-saaj-1.4.jar
    commons-discovery-0.2.jar javamail-mailapi-1.4.jar
    javax.activation.jar javax.xml.stream-1.0.1.jar jaxb-api.jar
    jaxb-impl.jar jaxrpc-api-1.1.jar log4j-1.2.17.jar ojdbc5.jar
    org.apache.commons.logging.jar wsdl4j-1.5.2.jar xerces-2.9.0
```

Any body has faced this problem already?